How to make an Equilateral Triangle Grid with Geometry Nodes?
I’ve been dying for an equilateral triangle grid mesh within geometry nodes for a while now!

I was attempting to make an equilateral triangle grid that can be controlled by the input parameters

length of a leg (float)
number of triangles in a row (integer)
number of rows within the grid (integer).

Obviously, I failed.

Can someone help fix my node tree by incorporating these parameters or come up with his/her own for this request?

Below is my attempt

Blender 4.1.1

Nothing elegant or unusual about this one at all, just plumbing..

Triangle : Mesh 3-circle, origin to mid Y.
In a row,every triangle rotated by pi*index
Duplicate rows as instances, every other row flipped by Y scale -1
Welding, face-flipping, to tidy up
All scaled at end to input edge-length


Options to fill, and point up / point down, for triangle 0.



really, Really, REALLY COOL!!! I had to wait until I got off work and gone home to test this out and this went beyond my expectations.

The Parity parameter was especially clever. kudos!

@Obfuscate    Thank you! I was hoping for a snappier way to do this, someone may yet come up with it.

"snappier way to do this" - I would go for my double thonk solution + removing the excess :D

@MarkusvonBroady  True. That would knock out a fair bit of faffing with rotations and reflections.



Unfortunately the subdivision method doesn't work because it's different in geonodes than in the edit mode... How do you create a triangle pattern in a plane?

Compared to my first try, I gotta give you 100 out of 10. lol. Really efficient!



You may want to realize instances and merge by distance.

lol. I thought this was just a rough attempt until I saw the comment you made on Robin's answer. I had to personally flesh out the final details to understand how your node tree actually works! +1 https://imgur.com/a/HmU2XHq

@Obfuscate the diamond could work like this too, but the diamond is very wasteful. Theoretically it could still be possible that the cost of temporarily hold a lot of unnecessary triangles is lower than the cost difference between spawning triangles in geonodes and in C++ implementation of geonodes (meaning, the less nodes you use the faster it is). This here is not very wasteful, at most you have to remove 2 rows and 2 columns, but you could reduce it to at most 1 row and 1 column is you dynamically adjust the repeated group.
